# Remove data using AWK

Tags: awk, gnuplot

I have a file of values that I wish to plot using gnuplot. The problem is that there are some values that I wish to remove.

Here is an example of my data:

```
1 52
2 3
3 0
4 4
5 1
6 1
7 1
8 0
9 0
```

I want to remove any row in which the right column is `0`, so the data above would end up looking like this:

```
1 52
2 3
4 4
5 1
6 1
7 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's just check field 2:

```
awk '$2' file
```

If the 2nd field has a True value, that is, not `0` or empty, the condition is True. In such case, `awk` performs its default action: `print $0`, meaning print the current line.

Comment: @axblount yes! See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Truth-Values.html _" In awk, any nonzero numeric value or any nonempty string value is true. Any other value (zero or the null string, "") is false"_.

Answer (score 3):

Updated, shorter:

```
awk '$2 == 0 { next; } { print; }'
```

```
awk '{ if ($2 == 0) { next; } else { print; } }'
```